# Is it an ODR violation to have an inline templated function have different behavior due to if constexpr?

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule, if-constexpr

It's possible to detect if a type is complete https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190710-00/?p=102678

I have reason to want to provide a different (inlinable) implementation if a type is complete.

Is it an ORD violation for a templated function to behave differently in different translation units based on an `if constexpr` in the function? In a sense, it's the "same" function in the different translation units (it's not macros creating different definitions at a C++ source level, which is an ODR violation).

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


// From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190710-00/?p=102678
template<typename, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_type_complete_v = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_type_complete_v
    <T, std::void_t<decltype(sizeof(T))>> = true;


template <typename T>
T* loggingGetRef(T* x) {
    if constexpr (is_type_complete_v<T>) {
        std::cout << "Complete!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Incomplete!" << std::endl;
    }
    return x;
}

struct S
//{} // <- Uncomment this to make loggingGetRef be "different" through if constexpr.
;

int main() {    
    S* ptr = nullptr;
    loggingGetRef(ptr);    
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q1soa58PY

For my application, I would want the two `if constexpr` branches to outwardly act the same (unlike this example that prints different things) so from a correctness standpoint, it would be OK if the linker picked the assembly for either implementation and used that everywhere. It's just that in a translation unit where `T` is complete we may be able to get better performance (and I fully expect it to be inlined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ODR is not based on "templated functions"; it is based on *actual* functions. Templates *generate* functions based on template parameters. Each unique set of template parameters represents a different function. Different functions generated from the same template are *different functions*. There are no ODR expectations between different functions, regardless of what created them.

`loggingGetRef<S>` is the name of a particular function. If you do something that causes `loggingGetRef<S>` to generate differently due to constant expressions, you have ill-formed code (no diagnostic required). But that isn't a matter of ODR violations; that's a violation of the rules of template instantiation. A template that is instantiated with a specific set of parameters must be the same in all translation units that instantiate it with those parameters. Period.

Comment: I think that answers it. But what about if different translation units have different optimization levels, producing different assembly code for the "exact same" function? 
Likewise, what about using `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())` to provide two implementations of the same function? I guess if that's `true` then there is no codegen, so the issue is moot since all the non-`std::is_constant_evaluated()` instantiations of the function will be the same?

Comment: @Ben: "*But what about if different translation units have different optimization levels*" The standard has nothing to say about "optimization levels". "*Likewise, what about using if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) to provide two implementations of the same function?*" You'll notice that this isn't `if constexpr`. It's the *same function*, simply one that runs two different paths. Both of those code paths must be legal, valid C++.

Comment: I see. Now that I think about it, is `constexpr bool is_type_complete_v` problematic because it has a different value in different translation units? It seems like maybe?: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf 6.2.12

Comment: @Ben: No, it's only a problem when it *does* have different values. It can be used in a way such that it doesn't (ie: for types that are *never* complete).

Comment: It sounds like you are saying `is_type_complete_v` is a footgun in that invites use in disparate places across a codebase that could easily wind up with it having different values (even depending on order of `#include`s!)

Comment: @Ben: Well, yes. It's not part of the C++ standard for a reason.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for thinking it through with me.